# Rails - Nest Attributes Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues understanding this.

**What am I trying to accomplish?**

- Selected items in dropdown submitted to inventory.
- Change the status of each item in a form in its own model.

**Problem**

- I submit a form and the status of each item in the dropdown doesn't get submitted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Form Code**

```
<%= form_for(@inventory, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @inventory.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@inventory.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this inventory from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @inventory.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :tablet_id, "Tablet #", class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= select("inventory", "tablet_id", Tablet.where("status = '1'").all.collect{ |t| [t.alias, t.id] }, {}, { class: "form-control"} ) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :tablet do |t| %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :status, value: 2 %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :chauffeur_id, "Chauffeur #", class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= select("inventory", "chauffeur_id", Chauffeur.where("status = '1'").all.collect{ |t| [t.chaufNum, t.id] }, {}, { class: "form-control"} ) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :chauffeur do |t| %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :status, value: 2 %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :vehicle_id, "Vehicle #", class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= select("inventory", "vehicle_id", Vehicle.where("status = '1'").all.collect{ |t| [t.vehNum, t.id] }, {}, { class: "form-control"} ) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :vehicle do |t| %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :status, value: 2 %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-sm btn-success" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Model (Inventory)**

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tablet
  belongs_to :chauffeur
  belongs_to :vehicle

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tablet
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :chauffeur
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle

  has_paper_trail

  validates :tablet_id, :chauffeur_id, :vehicle_id, presence: true
  validates :tablet_id, :chauffeur_id, :vehicle_id, uniqueness: { message: " is already checked out." }

end
```

**Inventory Controller**

```
class InventoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :set_paper_trail_whodunnit
  before_action :set_inventory, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /inventories
  # GET /inventories.json
  def index
    @inventories = Inventory.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
  end

  # GET /inventories/1
  # GET /inventories/1.json
  def show
    @versions = PaperTrail::Version.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /inventories/new
  def new
    @inventory = Inventory.new
  end

  # GET /inventories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def history
    @versions = PaperTrail::Version.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # POST /inventories
  # POST /inventories.json
  def create

    # @inventory = Inventory.new(inventory_params)

    render plain: params[:inventory].inspect

    # respond_to do |format|
    #   if @inventory.save
    #     format.html { redirect_to @inventory, notice: 'Inventory was successfully created.' }
    #     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @inventory }
    #   else
    #     format.html { render :new }
    #     format.json { render json: @inventory.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    #   end
    # end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /inventories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /inventories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @inventory.update(inventory_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @inventory, notice: 'Inventory was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @inventory }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @inventory.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /inventories/1
  # DELETE /inventories/1.json
  def destroy
    @inventory.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to inventories_url, notice: 'Inventory was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_inventory
      @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def inventory_params
      params.require(:inventory).permit(:tablet_id, :chauffeur_id, :vehicle_id, tablet_attributes: [:status => '2'], chauffeur_attributes: [:status => '2'], vehicle_attributes: [:status => '2'])
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi Allen, what do you see on your **rails console** when you submit the form under **Parameters:**? Could you add that to the question? If you find there other warning/error regarding parameters also paste it. Also, how does your create/update (the one that the console says it's executing on submit) action look like? If it's `create` action, also post your `new` action code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have placed all the Controller code above, I have updated it.. I have it in "inspect" and the only thing that gets submitted is the "tablet_id, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id" nothing else. 

{"tablet_id"=>"2", "chauffeur_id"=>"15", "vehicle_id"=>"1"}

Comment: Is it on edit or new mode?

Comment: Also, I assume the `[:status => '2']` is a test on the `inventory_params`?

Comment: here is my rails console output http://pastebin.com/LN9Gtue4

Comment: Yes, sorry, I left that in there.. it should be just [:status] but it still has the same outcome.

Comment: See if my answer helps. Let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean all your **nested attribute** code. This is not what you want. So model like this:

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tablet
  belongs_to :chauffeur
  belongs_to :vehicle

  has_paper_trail

  validates :tablet_id, :chauffeur_id, :vehicle_id, presence: true
  validates :tablet_id, :chauffeur_id, :vehicle_id, uniqueness: { message: " is already checked out." }
end
```

Now, what you want to use a rails `callback` so that when you create an inventory then you update the status of other things. This goes on your model too:

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  after_create :update_status

  protected

    def update_status
      self.tablet.update_attribute(:status, 2)
      self.chauffeur.update_attribute(:status, 2)
      self.vehicle.update_attribute(:status, 2)
    end
end
```

Also remember to clean all your `fields_for` code and your *strong parameters* on your controller...you don't need the nested ones anymore.

Comment: I did see that it passed the nested attributes but i get this.. error, which seems like its trying to create "New" tablets/chauffeurs/vehicles.

7 errors prohibited this inventory from being saved:
Tablet alias can't be blank
Tablet email can't be blank
Chauffeur chaufnum can't be blank
Vehicle vehnum can't be blank
Tablet can't be blank
Chauffeur can't be blank
Vehicle can't be blank

What it should be doing is placing the selected items into "Inventory" model(table) while taking "status" and changing it from 1->2 in each model (tablets/chauffeurs/vehicles).. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, if the problem is the `create` action like I said, then here you build everything, inventory with tablet, chauffeur and vehicle. Otherwise something is wrong since you shouldn't be executing this action - should be `edit`/`update`.

Comment: The inventory system is more like a check in and out. So you go to the inventory form to select which tablet is going with which chauffeur in which car. But as you are checking out these items/people/vehicles you are also updating their status so that in the dropdown for the next check out they wont be there because they are already checked out.

Does this help or is it still the same issue. I would assume I need to "Create" an inventory but not create new tablets/chauffeurs/vehicles as they are exsiting. If this process is wrong, I could use the help.

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: @Allen I think this is what you want, let me know.

Comment: You sir, are a god! I've been trying to figure this out for so long.. Weeks! And others kept telling me, you need nested attributes.. So last question but I think I know the answer but, say I want to destroy(check in) the inventory, i would create a callback on destroy to update it back to "1".. correct? thank you so much again!